# Python - Comparing a list of characters to a list of words?

Tags: python, string, compare, words, letters

I have built a program that randomly generates 8 separate letters and assigns them into a list called `ranlet` (short for random letters). It then imports a .txt file into a list called `wordslist`. Both the random generation of letters and loading the file works fine, as I have tested these parts individually, but then I hit a snag.

The program then must compare the `ranlet` list to the `wordslist` list, append the matching words to a list called `hits` and display the words in the `hits` list

I tried this:

```
for each in wordslist:
    if ranlet==char in wordslist:
        hits.append(wordslist)
    else:
        print "No hits."

print hits
```

Sadly, this didn't work. I have many more variations on this, but all to no avail. I would really appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Show example data, input and output.

Comment: sounds like a scrabble, words-with-friends or something type-code. maybe you should search for python scrabble implementations and just see what is done there.

Comment: You need to clarify some thing: when you say "matching words" do you mean 1) words with at least one letter from `ranlet`? 2) words with all 8 letters from `ranlet`? 3) words with all 8 letters from `ranlet`, in order? 4) words with only letters from `ranlet` and no other letters? 5) some other rule for what counts as "matching"?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could benefit from `set.intersection` here:

```
set_ranlet = set(ranlet)
for word in word_list:
    intersection = set_ranlet.intersection(word)
    if intersection:
        print "word contains at least 1 character in ran_let",intersection

    #The following is the same as `all( x in set_ranlet for x in word)`
    #it is also the same as `len(intersection) == len(set_ranlet)` which might
    # be faster, but less explicit.
    if intersection == set_ranlet: 
        print "word contains all characters in ran_let"
```

Comment: Let me know how I can improve this and I'm happy to update :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are new at `Python`, this may be an 'easy to understand' answer:

```
hits = []
for word in wordslist:
    if word in ranlet and word not in hits:
        hits.append(word)
print hits
```